# Java - open txt file and clear all multiple spaces

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have a txt file and what I am trying to do is open it and delete all multiple spaces so they become only one. I use:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\file_two.txt"));
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\file_two.txt"));

while ((current_line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     //System.out.println("Here.");
     current_line = current_line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    bw.write(current_line);
}        
br.close();
bw.close();
```

However, as it seems correct according to me at least, nothing is written on the file. If I use a system.out.println command, it is not printed, meaning that execution is never in the while loop... What do I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your code works for me using stringreaders and writers instead of files, so the loop and the close are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are reading the file and at the same time writing contents on it..it is not allowed...

so better way to read the file first and store the processed text in another file and finally replace the original file with the new one..try this

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\file_two.txt"));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\file_two_copy.txt"));
        String current_line;
        while ((current_line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println("Here.");
            current_line = current_line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            bw.write(current_line);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
        File copyFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\file_two_copy.txt");
        File originalFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\file_two.txt");
        originalFile.delete();
        copyFile.renameTo(originalFile);
```

it may help...

Answer (score 1):

You must read first then write, you are not allowed to read and write to the same file at the same time, you would need to use `RandomAccessFile` to do that.

If you don't want to learn a new technique, you will need to either write to a separate file, or cache all lines to memory(IE an `ArrayList`) but you must close the `BufferedReader` before you Initialize your `BufferedWriter`, or it will get a file access error.

Edit:
In case you want to look into it, here is a `RandomAccessFile` use case example for your intended use. It is worth pointing out this will only work if the final line length is less than or equal to the original, because this technique is basically overwriting the existing text, but should be very fast with a small memory overhead and would work on extremely large files:

```
public static void readWrite(File file) throws IOException{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    String line = null;
    int write_pos = 0;
    while((line = raf.readLine()) != null){
        line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ") + newLine;
        byte[] bytes = line.getBytes();
        long read_pos = raf.getFilePointer();
        raf.seek(write_pos);
        raf.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        write_pos += bytes.length;
        raf.seek(read_pos);
    }
    raf.setLength(write_pos);
    raf.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with your approach:

- Main one is that you are trying to read and write to same file at the same time.
- other is that `new FileWriter(..)` always creates new empty file which kind of prevents `FileReader` from reading anything from your file.

You should read content from `file1` and write its modified version in `file2`. After that replace `file1` with `file2`.

Your code can look more or less like

```
Path input = Paths.get("input.txt");
Path output = Paths.get("output.txt");

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(input);
lines.replaceAll(line -> line.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));

Files.write(output, lines);
Files.move(output, input, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```